# Convert hex to bytes

Tags: python, hex

I have results of script in text and bytes stored in CSV text file, which looks like:

> found_value_1;b'UT\x05\x00\x03'
>
> found_value_2;b'UT\x05\x00\x04'

There is some text and, separated by semicolon, dump of bytes.
I was seriously looking, but could not find instructions or examples on how could I read this file's corresponding part as bytes. Manually I can copy *b'UT\x05\x00\x03'* and paste it to a variable like this:

> *found_value_1 = b'UT\x05\x00\x03'*

and it is ready to go as type 'bytes'. It was simple to read this file and have 'u' type variables created with values like "b'UT\x05\x00\x03'" (probably having double-slashes), but as I tried converting it back to bytes nothing of available examples worked for me. Help is appreciated.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(r"b'UT\x05\x00\x03'")` => done.

Comment: I tried this: `variable = "b'UT\x05\x00\x03'" `
`variable_raw = "%r"%variable `
`result = ast.literal_eval(variable_raw)` 
`type(result)`

str

Comment: make it `variable = r"b'UT\x05\x00\x03'"` if you test on a literal

Comment: Imagine the file has more than 2 lines. If I could add `'r'` by hand to all values being read from file I would instead do `variable = b'UT\x05\x00\x03'`. This variable is already `bytes`

Comment: r is only for testing literals. You don't need it.

Comment: Ok, tried this out with the file.. seems working

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have your csv file. Read it and evaluate the bytes using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import csv,ast.literal_eval
with open("input.csv") as f:
   cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
   for row in cr:
      print(ast.literal_eval(row[1]))
```